# How do I make the Windows Remote Assistance window full screen?

Tags: remote-desktop, remote-assistance

When someone sends me a remote assistance request and I connect to their machine it doesn't appear that there is a way to make the window full screen.

Does anyone have way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Can you try **CTRL+ALT+BREAK** (Switch the client computer between a window and a full screen)

If it doesn't work, I'm not sure there is a way to do that.

Comment: This does indeed make it full screen but unfortunately the person I am assisting and myself both have dual monitors and it will full screen his two monitors on a single monitor of mine instead of full screening his two monitors across my two monitors.

Comment: Do you have an extended or splitted monitor.

Comment: In Windows 7 there is a drop down next to Multiple Displays: that has the options "Extend these displays", "Duplicate these displays", "Show desktop only on 1", "Show desktop only on 2". I have it set to "Extend these displays". PS I opened an additional question for the specific multimonitor scenario since you correctly answered the question that I had asked here.

Comment: I have the same issue but don't see a break/pause key on my keyboard. How can I do that anyway?

Answer (score -1):

Select "Actual Size" (see image) and it will enlarge to one screen actual size, vice two screens smashed together on one monitor.  You can scroll left and right to see the users other screen if needed.

[image: Select "Actual Size" (see image) and it will enlarge to one screen actual size, vice two screens smashed together on one monitor. You can scroll left and right to see the users other screen if needed.]

Comment: That does not full screen the assistance window.